# Checking for replication options

Tags: mysql, replication, my.cnf

I have a master/master setup with one DB in each. DB name and tables in one server are different from the other, and few 'user' tables are being *replicated* with the option `replicate-do-table`. (It's amazing how devs chose to sync the tables this way)

Is there a way to check what type of replication options were used? In specific I want to know if `replicate-rewrite-db` option was used. I checked all my.cnf file and I don't see it, and this info is not in global variables.

Comment: What version of MySQL server are you running?

Comment: Assuming you're not using 5.7, this is a tough one to get out of a running server. (I'll say impossible in the hopes someone can prove me wrong.) The only way to set it, though, is via a .cnf or on the command line when you start MySQL, so as long as you're sure you have the right .cnf file(s) and don't see it indicated in your process list (ps -ef), then it's not been set. I notice the relay log on the slave shows the original database, so you could do an extra sanity check and grep in there over a period of days for databases not on the slave.